# Flutter System Navigation bar and Status bar color

Tags: dart, navbar, flutter

How do I change the system NavBar using Android Studio and flutter?

I presume it's not in the main.dart, and I need to go through the android system files, but when I tried to edit the style.xml, the theme editor didn't let me edit any of the colors.

Any help would be appreciated, I wanted to have a light NavBar to go with a light bottom AppBar.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

*Note: this requires a more recent version of Flutter as it references APIs added in June 2018*.

You can create a custom `SystemUiOverlayStyle` using the default constructor.  The color of the system nav bar is defined there.  But to avoid setting a lot of null values, use the `copyWith` method to update the values from an existing light/dark theme.

```
const mySystemTheme= SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
 .copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red);
```

You can imperatively set the system nav color using the `SystemChrome` static methods.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlayStyle(mySystemTheme);
```

However, if you have multiple widgets which set this value, or use the material AppBar or Cupertino NavBar your value may be overwritten by them.  Instead, you could use the new AnnotatedRegion API to tell flutter to automatically switch to this style anytime certain widgets are visible.  For example, if you wanted to use the theme above anytime you are in a certain route, you could wrap it in an AnnotatedRegion widget like so.

```
Widget myRoute(BuildContext context) {
  return new AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: mySystemTheme,
    child: new MyRoute(),
  );
}
```

This *won't* change your theme back to the previous value if you pop the route however

Comment: Awesome ! But what happens if you have multiple `AnnotatedRegion` with conflicting values ? And if the previous route contains an `AnnotatedRegion`, is your last statement still valid ?

Comment: Currently the flutter view combines the system chrome values which intersect at the top and bottom of the screen in the actual layer tree. So it you have 3 annotated regions at the top of your screen, the last one will be chosen.

This is kind of a low level API, and we intend to build a simpler one on top of it in material and cupertino

Comment: "last" meaning deepest, unless it is unsized :)

Comment: @JonahWilliams you said, "This won't change your theme back to the previous value if you pop the route however". Is there any option for changing the status bar color after pop or push to new route?

Comment: @JonahWilliams I tried to use the `AnnotatedRegion` as the parent of a `Scaffold`, defining `statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,`, but it doesn't work, it appears that the `AppBar` has always precedence.

Comment: Updated from 'SystemUiOverlayStyle' to 'setSystemUIOverlayStyle'

Comment: So what is the solution for pop?

Comment: I can't stop material `AppBar` screw up my `AnnotatedRegion`...

Answer (score 55):

#### Flutter 2.4+ (Update)

Use `systemOverlayStyle` property

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue, // Navigation bar
          statusBarColor: Colors.pink, // Status bar
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Not sure how you did. Can you post it as a question

Comment: I just copied your code into main. Thx a lot!

Comment: This should be accept as answer. obs: Only works on recent android version.

Comment: Doesn't work on latest android version

Comment: @Jeremi You can [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md) on Github.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

Comment: This worked, but is quite temperamental as sometimes it works, and often only after a few hot reloads, but guess that's better than nothing for now!

Comment: It does not work on IOS

Comment: @Tom were you able to run this code on ios?