# Status bar color doesn't change in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a page that I want to have different style, I've tried to change status bar color from example through SystemChrome like this:

```
class PageState extends State<Page> {
 @override
 void initState() {
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
     SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white));
 super.initState();
 }
}
```

And also set up appBar theme:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```

But status bar still uses default color from home page.
Also worth mentioning that if I try to change color with this method on home page it works just fine.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but thought maybe I could resolve the issue without adding another library just for one screen

Comment: Maybe something like from the top solution where you make your own https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012360/flutter-system-navigation-bar-and-status-bar-color

Comment: What color do you need in the status bar ? and what color are you getting ?

Comment: @Hosar I want it to be white, but I'm getting red color (the one I set on home page)

Comment: @JoeA doesn't seem to have any effect either

Comment: SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith( statusBarColor: Colors.white, )); something like that maybe with the package services.dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set status bar color you should write code in 'build' method, as below example -

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
            statusBarColor: Color.fromRGBO(41, 167, 77, 50),
            //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
    return Scaffold();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, my bad

Comment: It's not a good idea to put code like this in `build`, because it will execute every time your widget needs building (possibly hundreds or thousands of times!) Better to put it somewhere which will execute once, eg in `initstate`

Comment: But I don't understand why changing it in the ThemeData doesn't change it