# Bottom Navigation bar color in flutter revert to black

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when changing the bottom navigation bar color in flutter using these lines of code inside main method:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
));
```

**it works fine** but the bottom navBar color revert to black after some times **when using SilverAppBar** inside main page :

```
body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 300,
        floating: false,
        pinned: true,
        snap: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[

        ]),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

**when changing the value of**  `expandedHeight: 250` the color of bottom navBar won't change,
so the problem is inside `expandedHeight` value , so why and how to fix that .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is actually not inside the `expandedHeight` value, but rather it's the fact that the sliver app bar internally uses an `AnnotatedRegion` to set the system ui overlay style: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart#L599

Since you only set the overlay style once in the main method, the new overlay style exposed by the `AnnotatedRegion` in the app bar will override the old one.

So what you can do is to wrap your `FlexibleSpaceBar` within your `SliverAppBar` with another `AnnotatedRegion`, to override the `AnnotatedRegion` that is already in the app bar:

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 300,
  floating: false, 
  pinned: true,
  snap: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  flexibleSpace: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    child: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
  ),
),
```

#### Just for your info

`AnnotatedRegion` is another way to change the ui overlay style, you can learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013116/6064621

Comment: it's working perfectly, I'm wondering if we can consider this as a bug.